# Detaching Entities in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, detach

I have an issue with detaching entities in JPA 2.1 EclipseLink.

I have a JavaEE application with a some entities that have all relationships set to lazy loading. I use join fetch in all my database queries in order to fetch only the objects I need. I use Jackson (FasterXml) for converting objects to JSON (for JAX-RS, etc.)

Whenever I select any entity from the database, I detach that entity before returning it to avoid running too many queries on the database when Jackson converts that object to JSON, (since this conversion calls all the getters in the entity being converted).

My problem is that the detaching does not work, and when I look at the JPA logs I see that all members of the entity being converted and being loaded by a query on the database. This happens when Jackson converts the object to JSON, and my guess is that it is because Jackson calls the getters while converting the object. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: unfetched lazy attributes aren't the same as being null, so you would get an exception if you accessed them outside the context. EclipseLink will allow fetching attributes for as long as the context around, so you are going to want to implement either your own accessor methods that check if a lazy attribute was fetched for Jackson to use, or read in java objects instead of entities that wrap the data for Jackson to use.  see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Constructors

Comment: @Chris what do you mean by implementing my own accessor methods? Do you mean checking in the getters whether the attribute is lazy? Also I am aware that I could select into a POJO and that would prevent this issue completely, but I don't like this solution so I'm leaving it as a last resort. Some queries fetch objects with many attributes and use join fetch, so it would be a hassle and would look unsettling if I select using the new operator

Comment: @Chris I think this is a serious flaw of EclipseLink. If they don't give us a way to detach an entity, then they must give at least a "xx.xxx.EnableAutoFetching" property to control it.

Answer (score 0):

Detach for EclipseLink was thought only to be used to stop tracking changes, pulling it out of the EM for performance reasons. Accessing an unfetched attribute, according to the JPA spec results in an exception; something that no user seemed to really request early on, so the behaviour was not implemented. If you want this behaviour, request it.

Anyone can check the fetch state of a lazy property within their accessor and throw an application exception. This would require modifying the resulting enhanced java code that EclipseLink generates with weaving to access the lazy properties.

Another solution might be to use a [constructor query](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Constructors). Constructor queries, instead of returning managed entity objects, pass the select values to a java constructor, so only data fetched within the query are included. These objects are not entities, and so are completely detached, and any java object can be built, even existing Entity classes.